# How to generate a warning message when the contents of a specific page exceeds half a page in length?

Tags: luatex, warnings, toptesi

Consider the following MWE:

```latex
\documentclass{toptesi}
\usepackage{lipsum} % just for dummy text

\begin{document}

\sommario

\lipsum[1-3]

\end{document}
```

Typically, the “sommario” (or “abstract” in English) should not exceed half a page. **How can I create a warning message to appear when the sommario exceeds this limit?**

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

this logs:

```
Warning:abstract too long!
418.0pt/607.50787pt
```

---

```
\documentclass{toptesi}
\usepackage{lipsum} % just for dummy text

\begin{document}

\sommario


% \lipsum[1-2]% OK
 \lipsum[1-3]% warning

\ifdim\pagetotal>0.6\pagegoal % a bit spare adjust as needed
\typeout{^^JWarning:abstract too long!}
\fi
\typeout{\the\pagetotal/\the\pagegoal^^J}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you so much, David! I am curious to know if does your approach consider also the title of the page ("Abstract" or "Sommario")? If so, is it possible to exclude it since I would like the **content** of the page to take up at the most half of the page?
I mean that visually you can have a content longer that the half of the page but excluding the title doesn't exceed the half.

Comment: it just measures the point on the page which is why I said you might want to adjust the 0.6 for whatever value you want to account for title or vertical space, etc.  You could do more: grabbing the abstract in a box, measuring it etc, but it's a lot more, and really a different answer. @miticollo I would just make an example with the smallest abstract that should give a warning and then just adjust the 0.6 so the warning appears on that example and not any smaller one